# Angular cli hook

Tags: templates, build, hook, angular-cli

I am looking for way to modify output of build function from

```
ng build --prod
```

would like to add some bootstrap css files to head section of index.html, change name index.html => index.php etc.

how to do it ?

Answer (score 3):

You can customise the implementation from the source code. This [section](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#development-hints-for-hacking-on-angular-cli) explains how you can proceed.

In particular, you can change the following lines from [addon/ng2/models/webpack-build-common.ts](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/webpack/addon/ng2/models/webpack-build-common.ts).

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: path.resolve(projectRoot, `./${sourceDir}/index.php`),
    chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
  })
```

For the CSS resources, they can be packaged directly if you use [Webpack Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/WEBPACK_UPDATE.md).

**EDIT**

The key index in the apps nodes can be modified in the angular-cli.json file. The line should be changed to

```
"index": "index.php",
```

Comment: All 3 link are either broken or no longer relevant. Is there a solution to this ever since they removed angular-cli-build.js in favor of angular-build.json?

Comment: You can use the node index in the angular-cli.json file to specify the name of the index file.

Answer (score 0):

I find work around this process. In package.json modify build script to:

```
"build": "ng build .......... && mv dist/index.html dist/index.php"
```